# targeting parent element with twitter button

Tags: javascript, twitter, frameset

i'm trying to do something a little bit tricky here. i'm having a FRAMESET page with 2 frames , header and content (this one is variable). The page url looks like page.php?url=xxx (xxx will be the content frame). What i'm trying to do is to put a twitter share button on the top header frame and make it share the whole page. Here's the twitter js code :

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

To show the button i have to put this code :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="SpotMaroc" data-lang="fr">Tweeter</a>
```

I tried to put :

```
target="_parent"
```

on the seconde code but it didn't work , it shared only the header frame.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the Twitter button point directly to your complete URL?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=X" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="SpotMaroc" data-lang="fr">Tweeter</a>
```

Where **X** is **yourdomain.com/page.php?url=xxx**

Comment: Actually i got a lot of pages generated this way. So it can be static. Maybe i can put some javascript to replace X by the URL ? i don't know how to do that .

Comment: Well, how are you generating your pages? If you're using a server side programming language like PHP or ASP.Net, you should be able to write the URL of the page into the markup while its being "generated".